# Test class failure?

Tags: code-coverage, failing-tests

[image]

```
Acc.name=(Acc.name).toUppercase(); // Here getting account name and make it uppercase
 Exaccounts.add(Acc.name);  // here storing account name.
```

Comment: Have you inserted accounts and sure that there are records returning from Account query?

Comment: yes,see my test class code

Comment: Account Parentacc1=new account();
        Parentacc1.recordtypeid=AccrecId;
        Parentacc1.Name=('test Murugan').toUppercase();
        Parentacc1.IKA_Type__c='Renault';
        Parentacc1.Scoring__c='Bronze';
        Parentacc1.Industry='Other';
        Parentacc1.Account_Type__c='Customer';
        Parentacc1.Status_RFLEET__c='Customer';
        insert Parentacc1;
     
        Account acc=[select id,Name,Rfleet_Country_Code__c from account where id=:Parentacc1.id];

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there, that improves highly the readability :)

Comment: is test execution failing or it is not covering those lines? and add you test class  in your question.

Comment: it is not covering

Comment: Its better if you update your question with your test class.

Comment: You are doing an insert call right ? And I really hope you are not doing a query for 50k accounts in a trigger! You want to use a where  soql statement to limit the results to the trigger accounts ..

Answer (score 1):

Kindly Check the debug logs. I, think the account insertion did not happen properly.

```
System.Debug('Acc Elements '+Acc);
Acc.Name=(Acc.Name).toUppercase();
```